# How to determine last NAL of an Access Unit in H.264

Tags: h.264

When parsing NAL units from a H.264 source is it possible to determine the end of an Access Unit without having to find the start of the next one?  I am aware of the following section in the H.264 spec:

**7.4.1.2.4 Detection of the first VCL NAL unit of a primary coded picture**

And I have currently implemented this.  The problem here though, is that if there is a large time gap at the end of an Access Unit I won't 'get' the Access Unit until the start of the next one.  Is there another way to determine the *end* (ie. last NAL) of an Access Unit?

I am also aware of the Marker Bit in the RTSP standard but it is not reliable enough for us to use.  And in some cases it is just plain wrong.

Comment: Hi, did you find out the answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

no, I don't think so. 
Unreliable marker bit is the only way to signal end of access unit (in case of RTP).
They should have handled it more reliably in h.264 payload (rfc 6184).

You can check for timestamps and sequence number to infer start of new AU but that is also unreliable (packet loss, reordering, need to wait for first packet of next AU)